# HighCharts:set the value of yAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have combine tow line and column in one chart like this 
[image]

I want set the right yAxis show {0%, 20%, 40% 60%, 80%, 100%},
and left yAxis show {0, 10k, 20k, 30k, 40k, 50k}

Comment: Try to put an example code on jsfiddle

Comment: jsfiddle demo : http://jsfiddle.net/QzXbg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **tickPositions** (http://jsfiddle.net/QzXbg/1/):

```
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Actual and forecast',
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                tickPositions: [0, 10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000]
            }, { // Secondary yAxis
                title: {
                    text: 'MAPE',
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                tickPositions: [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                labels: {
                    style: {
                        color: '#4572A7'
                    }
                },
                opposite: true
            }],
```

Comment: This is the link to the API for tickPositions: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use the tickInterval property for each axis, and avoid having to specify each tick individually.

ie:

```
yAxis:[{
   tickInterval:10000
},{
   tickInterval:20
}]
```

Assuming your date for the right axis is already in the % value that you need.
If not, you will need to calculate the % in the formatter for the axis labels.